# Perguntas do tipo, "será que existe uma palavra portuguesa assim?"

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Eu costumo ter dúvidas do tipo, "existe uma palavra portuguesa que parece como *<assim>* e com significado parecido a *<assim>*?". Seríam bem-vindos neste site perguntas deste tipo?

Acho que se encaixaria perfeitamente se fosse uma palavra (mal-) ouvido num contexto português. Mas, no meu caso, estas perguntas são motivadas pelo crioulo cabo-verdiano, uma língua que tem raiz português, mas simplesmente não *é* português. Muitas vezes uma palavra crioula aparece-me com morfologia portuguesa, más eu não consigo encontrar nenhum cognato nos dicionários.

Já sei que este site não é lugar certo para perguntar sobre o crioulo, mas: **seria bom ideia perguntar "será que existe tal palavra em português?" se a motivação vem duma outra língua?** Por um lado, não quero encher o site com perguntas inúteis que podem não ter nenhuma resposta, mas por outro lado minhas dúvidas são sobre a língua portuguesa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, eu acho que sim.

Acho que este formato de perguntas é claramente *on-topic*:

> Existe alguma palavra para dizer que algo está mal construído devido a falta de empenho?
>
> Procuro um adjetivo, palavra ou expressão que me permita exprimir isso curtamente.

E o equivalente de tradução também cabe perfeitamente cá:

> Em inglês, a palavra "oogablerk" é um adjetivo que significa "book blerk ganerk". Como posso dizer isto em português?
> Exemplos:
>
> - John behaved like a true ooglaberk on the last match.
> - The older ooglabrk lady reminded me of my grandma.

Comment: Também considero on-topic.